# Scrapy 404 Error INFO: Ignoring response <404 http://www.mega.pk/laptop-hp>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website however i keep getting the 404 error. This is the code i am using:
I am also using Scrapy version 1.6.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class PracticeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'practice'
    allowed_domains = ['www.mega.pk']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://www.mega.pk/laptop-hp", callback=self.parse, headers={

            'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Mobile Safari/537.36"

        })

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath(
            "//ul[contains(@class,'clearfix')]/li/div[@class='lap_thu_box']")
        for product in products:
            name = product.xpath(
                ".//ul[@class='detailer']/li[position()=1]/text()").get()

            yield{

                'name': name
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you entered in incorrect. You forgot a slash in your URL. Enter http://www.mega.pk/laptop-hp in your browser and it will give you a 404 error. Add the slash and enter http://www.mega.pk/laptop-hp/ It should work. Also it is wise to use the lastest version of Scrapy 2.1.0.

Comment: Thanks you so much!! And yes i was considering to move but is the syntax too different from version 1.6? because i purchased a course on udemy which teaches using scrapy version 1.6 which is the only reason i'm using it.